# Adding ultrasonic sensor to the robot

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am new to ROS and was using gazebo for simulation of Innok_Heros robot. Is it possible to add ultrasonic sensor to this robot, if yes can someone please hint me on the method to do the same.

Thank you.

-FAIZ.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260131/adding-ultrasonic-sensor-to-the-robot/) by [FAIZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/28020/faiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the `gazebo_ros_range` plugin to simulate an ultrasonic (sonar) sensor. Look at lines 82 to 115 of [this test world file](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/test/test_worlds/gazebo_ros_range.world#L82) to see how to add one to your own simulated robot.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FAIZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/28020/faiz/) on 2017-04-25**:
Thank you for the reply, I am using urdf file. Will this work on that.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-25**:
Yes, you can put the relevant information in your URDF file wrapped in a `<gazebo>` tag. See [this tutorial on using URDF with Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) and [this one on adding a laser scanner to the URDF](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#GPULaser).

**Comment by [Ahmad Altarabeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/105260/ahmad-altarabeen/) on 2022-05-18**:
Does this work for ROS2 ?

**Comment by [mrubio](https://answers.ros.org/users/123345/mrubio/) on 2022-11-10**:
Look at [ROS 2 Migration](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Ray-sensors#overview) for the ported version of the range sensor plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with the top answer, I tried it, it worked for me.

You can have a look at my code if you want:

https://github.com/OpenPi-bot/robot-simulation/tree/sensor :)

The code for the sensor is plugin is in this file:

https://github.com/OpenPi-bot/robot-simulation/blob/sensor/fb_description/urdf/fb.gazebo

---

Originally posted by [mananmadman](https://answers.ros.org/users/56484/mananmadman/) with karma: 21 on 2020-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2022-08-04**:
works for me on Noetic.